# Getting an error while installing Ruby On Rails on Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, webpack

I tried installing Ruby on Rails on my OS X Catalina (10.15) and had two issues that are maybe related. On the final step [here](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina)  it says

> "Mojave changed the location of header files necessary for compiling C extensions. You might need to run the following command to install pg, nokogiri, or other gems that require C extensions:
>   sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
>   "

For that step i do not have a folder packages under my command line tools folder so this line i could not run. So I ignored it and continue with the instructions. Then when i got to the last command in this instructions guide "rails server" the server tried to run and i got this run time error:

> /Users/yoramaharony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/yoramaharony/dev/myapp/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/yoramaharony/dev/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)

I do not have experience running terminal command but i am pretty sure i followed the [guide](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina)  diligently so why the last step is giving me error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` in order to set up Webpacker dependencies. Rails 6 introduces Webpacker as the default JavaScript tool for bundling JavaScript code. You could read more about it [in this blog by Prathamesh Sonpatki](https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/)

Comment: Thank you Anuj, would you know how to bundle exec rails webpacker on mac? If I try to run the command you posted i get this : "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ director"

Comment: Is there some log along with it?